# Не могу авторизоваться на сайте, requests

Tags: python, requests, сессия

Выполняю заказ, и нужно через скрипт авторизоваться на [сайте](https://mygreenway.co.ua/) (только `requests`, без `Selenium`!) но каким бы я образом не пытался - не удается авторизоваться. В ответе приходит

`{'Message': 'Помилка авторизації: Логін або пароль зазначений невірно', 'Status': 'Error', 'ErrorCode': 2}`, хотя пароль верный, и через сайт удается авторизоваться,
либо иногда получаю:

`Сессия была закрыта или неактивна`.

Если открыть `Network` в браузере, и посмотреть на данные, которые отправляются `POST` запросом, то можно увидеть, что там почему-то передается не пароль, а значение из 32 символов, как я понимаю это `session_id`, но если и его передавать, то тоже не авторизуется.
Когда нужно передать реальный пароль для `POST`-запроса? В инспекторе нигде нет и слова о передаче моего реального пароля (он состоит только из 6 или 8 цифр).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю - нужно сделать 1 `POST`-запрос, чтобы получить `sesion_id`, а потом второй - чтобы авторизоваться. Вот такие данные нужно передать для того, чтобы получить `session_id`, как я понимаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
import requests

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': user_agent})


url = "https://mygreenway.co.ua/s/l/"
session.headers.update({'Referer': url})


auth = {
    "type": "auth",
    "action": "sessionkey"
}

ses = session.post(url, data=auth)
key = ses.json()['Key']
print(key)

data = {
    "type": "auth",
    "action": "login",
    "REMEMBER": "0",
    "NAME": "1234567",
    "PASSWORD": key
}

ses2 = session.post('https://mygreenway.co.ua/s/l/', data=data)
print(ses2.text)
with open("result.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(ses2.text)
session.close()
```

UPD. Копнул чуть глубже, посмотрел как реализован запрос через JavaScript. Там передается пароль с учетом MD5-хэша, но даже если и создавать подобный хэш - все равно не удается авторизоваться. Возможно я неправильно собираю этот хэш. Буду пробовать

`req = {method:'post', dataType:'json', data:{type:'auth', action:'login', REMEMBER:($('#remembermeModal').prop('checked')==true?1:0), NAME:$('#nameModal').val(), PASSWORD:(MD5(key+MD5($('#passwordModal').val())))}};`

Comment: Да, теперь заработало! Почти 6 часов убитого времени, и теперь можно авторизоваться. Чуть позже оставлю ответ. Вспомнил, как когда-то на patreon был курс Молчанова по парсингу, я не особо обратил тогда внимание, что пароль может еще и шифроваться с помощью MD5,  но видимо отложилось в голове:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему решил следующим образом:

Заглянул в `JavaScript` код на сайте

`req = {method:'post', dataType:'json', data:{type:'auth', action:'login', REMEMBER:($('#remembermeModal').prop('checked')==true?1:0), NAME:$('#nameModal').val(), PASSWORD:(MD5(key+MD5($('#passwordModal').val())))}};`

и увидел, что пароль для `POST`-запроса нужно отправлять в формате:

`MD5('session_id' + MD5('your_passwd'))`

Итоговый код ниже:

```
from hashlib import md5
import requests

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36'
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': user_agent})

url = "https://mygreenway.co.ua/s/l/"
session.headers.update({'Referer': url})

ses = session.post(url, data={"type": "auth", "action": "sessionkey"})
key = ses.json()['Key']
passwd = "your password"
my_key = key + md5(passwd.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
my_md5_key = md5(my_key.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
data = {
    "type": "auth",
    "action": "login",
    "REMEMBER": 0,
    "NAME": "12345678",
    "PASSWORD": my_md5_key
}
# авторизация
session.post("https://mygreenway.co.ua/s/l/", data=data)
# и дальше операции с сайтом
session.close()
```